# Silent Install Visual Studio 2015 on new VM before logging into machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, silent-installer

I am having issues when trying to install Visual Studio 2015 on a virtual machine. The VM is being provisioned automatically and the install runs as part of a script shortly after the virtual machine is cloned.

My issue is when I start the installation, I believe, is that I don't have a user profile loaded as the user I'm running the install as. The user is added to the local admin group so access isn't a problem.

The install completes, but takes around 4 hours to do so. This is because it hangs when trying to write logs to the users temp directory (which doesn't exist). I have the logging set to a folder that does exist on the machine, and 99% of logs do go there, however when running the ultimate finalizer, modernblend finalizer, and vsgraphics vsga finalizer, it writes the logs to the temp directory and I have no control over this (that I can find). Here is an excerpt from those logs

```
MSI (s) (74:78) [15:29:37:694]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI5EB8.tmp, Entrypoint: LogCustomAction
MSI (s) (74:74) [15:29:37:694]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (74:74) [15:29:37:694]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 5240 (0x1478).
MSI (s) (74:A4) [15:29:37:709]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (74:A4) [15:29:37:709]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated Non-remapped custom action server.
05/18/17 15:29:37 DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033
05/18/17 15:29:37 DDSet_Entry: AppID Logged Custom Action started
05/18/17 15:29:37 DDSet_Status: CustomActionData: E:\Applications\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe;/setup /AllowDuringSetup 
05/18/17 15:29:37 DDSet_Status: Appid Custom Action will log to C:\Users\USJECE2\AppData\Local\Temp\VS1.tmp
05/18/17 15:29:37 DDSet_Status: Launching "E:\Applications\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup /AllowDuringSetup  /log "C:\Users\USJECE2\AppData\Local\Temp\VS1.tmp"
MSI (s) (74:88) [16:21:07:403]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (74:88) [16:21:08:179]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (74:AC) [16:21:30:551]: Running as a service.
05/18/17 15:29:37 DDSet_Entry: Starting process, will wait for up to 60 minutes to complete...
05/18/17 16:29:37 DDSet_Warning: Unable to open logfile
05/18/17 16:29:37 DDSet_Error: Timeout while waiting on process handle
05/18/17 16:29:37 DDSet_CARetVal: CA_E1B8E5023B1F
MSI (s) (74!60) [16:29:37:722]: Closing MSIHANDLE (92326) of type 790531 for thread 864
05/18/17 16:29:37 DDSet_Exit: AppID Logged Custom Action completed
MSI (s) (74:78) [16:29:37:722]: Closing MSIHANDLE (92325) of type 790536 for thread 5208
```

And here is the command line I'm running when I start the process

```
E:\temp\VisualStudio\vs2015_installer\vs2015_installer.exe /adminfile E:\temp\VisualStudio\vs2015_installer\AdminDeployment.xml /quiet /norestart /Log "E:\logs\VS2015.log"
```

And here is the bundle customizations portion of the admin file

```
<BundleCustomizations TargetDir="E:\Applications\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" NoCacheOnlyMode="default" NoWeb="default" NoRefresh="default" SuppressRefreshPrompt="default" Feed="default" />
```

If I log into the machine then logout and run the script, this isn't an issue, however, these machines are being provisioned automatically and there is no user interaction until the machine has been successfully built, including the silent install.

Thanks!

Comment: The installer should use the `TEMP` (or maybe `TMP`) environment variable to determine the temporary directory.

Comment: @RossRidge When I run as Local System, it attempts to use the TEMP directory (Something like C:\Windows\TEMP). The file does exists at that time. I downloaded ProcMon and it appears to be file lock conflict when running. 

Odd because if I run this as Local System, or as user X, and I log into the machine as user Y before the scripts gets to this part, there is no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY FIGURED THIS OUT. Even if this helps one person in the world I would be happy. I walked away from this and just installed VS 2017. I was asked to do it again so I went down a different route. I happened to install 2015 succesfully, but that was by luck.

To install it, I needed to install ASP.NET 4.0. Make sure that you don't install 3.0 because it will fail, even if you also install 4.0. I hope this saves someone else from hours and hours of troubleshooting.